# How to pass two dimensional data from controller to view?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller where i loop a query to model. All the data are saved in an array which is passed to view. But i am not getting the data in view.

This is my controller code part:

```
$data['bar_chart']=NULL;
$field='count(case_register.caseid)as totalcount';
for ($year = 2010; $year <= date('Y'); $year++)
{
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) 
{            
$condition=' MONTH(case_register.dated) ='.$month.' AND YEAR(case_register.dated) ='.$year;
$data['bar_chart'][]=$this->Model_name->cases_list($field,$condition);
}   
}
return $data['bar_chart'];
```

My view part is

```
<?php
foreach($bar_chart as $value){
echo $value['totalcount'];
echo ",";
}
?>
```

Comment: show where you are loading the view and how you are passing the variables as that is essentially where your issue lies

Answer (score 0):

In your controller update this code,

```
$data['bar_chart'][]=$this->Model_name->cases_list($field,$condition);
```

to

```
$data['bar_chart']['cases_list']=$this->Model_name->cases_list($field,$condition);
```

So in your view,

```
foreach($bar_chart['cases_list'] as $value)
{
  // do something
}
```